# Postgres doesn't shut down properly

Tags: mac-osx, postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Here is my original error:

```
$ psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
  Is the server running locally and accepting
  connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

and in Rails...

```
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I've searched around and found about a dozen answers on this -- The underly issue is that when I shut down my computer `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` does not get removed - implying postgres isn't shutdown properly.  I've read that you should NOT delete the pid (as is often recommended) but instead kill it, even with `kill -9` – but again, this is a temporary solution and suggests an underlying error.

EDIT: I could run `cat /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` the first line gives me the the process id.  I had this wrong originally.

When I run `tail -r /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log | less` to see the server log (in reverse) I get:

```
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1167) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1167) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?
FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
LOG:  database system is shut down
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  received smart shutdown request
LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding

...

LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG:  using stale statistics instead of current ones because stats collector is not responding
LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
LOG:  database system was shut down at 2016-05-25 17:36:26 MDT
LOG:  database system is shut down
LOG:  shutting down
LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
LOG:  received smart shutdown request
```

It looks like the database shuts down correctly, but if it was I believe the `postmaster.pid` file would be removed like it is when I run e.g. `brew services stop postgres`.

Comment: What's the timestamp on that `postmaster.pid` file?

Answer (score 1):

The file `/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` is not a PID in itself, it is a text file that contains a PID. In this case it seems to be 1167. Try `cat /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`. The file is there because for some reason postgres was shut down uncleanly.

If this PID 1167 exists (`ps -p $(cat /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid)` should work to check), then you should not delete the file.  If you remove the file while you have a postgres running, and then try to restart postgres, you very probably risk severe damage to the database.

You should stop the postgres process, by any means up to and including `kill -9` --  **but this last only if necessary**. Start with the normal commands, escalate to `kill` and only if that doesn't work to `kill -9`.

Once (or if) you do not have a process with the PID in the file, then you can remove the file.

Actually, I thought postgres would detect that the process did not exist any more and remove the file itself, but understandably I have not experimented too much with this! Maybe it depends on the version.

Comment: Your answer is very thorough and really good, but it doesn't _quite_ answer my question -- why doesn't postgres shutdown properly when I shut down my computer?  Is there any more info I can give you?  Thank you!

Comment: Right; could you provide the logs for when postgres is running correctly and you shut off the machine?